# User.Identity for user account page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-identification

In my application I use `User.Identity` to get the username of the user logged in, I was wondering if I can use this to get email and password information as I want a user account page where the user can view there email username etc.. and change their password.

I also have a web service called ***getusers*** which gets all the information from the users table in my database but then I am unsure of how to get the account information from the database for the user logged in if I do it this way.

So far I have this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        username.Text = User.Identity.Name;
    }

    localhost.Service1 myws = new localhost.Service1();
    ds = myws.GetUsers();

}
```

Which is great because I get the username, but I need the rest.

Oh and here is the web service GetUsers:

```
[WebMethod]
    public DataSet GetUsers()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string database = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|/dvd_forum.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";
        string queryStr = "select * from Users";
        OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(database);
        OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryStr, myConn);
        myConn.Open();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Users");
        myConn.Close();
        return ds;
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I must warn you that your `GetUsers()` method is open to SQL Injection. That aside...

If you modified that `GetUsers()` method slightly to accept a parameter and narrow down the search to a unique user, you could have:

```
[WebMethod] 
public DataSet GetUser(string UserName) 
{ 
    DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
    string database = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|/dvd_forum.accdb;Persist Security Info=True"; 
    string queryStr = "select * from Users WHERE UserName=" + UserName; 
    OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(database); 
    OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryStr, myConn); 
    myConn.Open(); 
    myDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Users"); 
    myConn.Close(); 
    return ds; 
}
```

Now all you need to do is call

```
GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
```

assuming the username is stored in the database, you'll get your User's record returned in the dataset.

Comment: Yeah I will be getting to the SQL injection soon. I had to change your code like this -> http://pastebin.com/rKPL8yw9 but when I invoke a username in the service it returns empty xml.

Comment: If you run the querystring in something like Managment Studio do you get a result?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MembershipUser class in your asp.net application then you can check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx).

Here is a snippet of code.

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  u = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);

  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    EmailTextBox.Text = u.Email; 
  }
}
```